# Jenkins not listening on port?

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, jenkins

I'm trying to install Jenkins CI, and I followed [these](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions) instructions to install it. Everything went smoothly, and when I go `ps aux | grep jenkins` I can see that jenkins is running:

> java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle-20

However, when I run try to connect to port 8080, it doesn't work, even on localhost:

> $ wget localhost:8080
>
> (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... failed: Connection refused. $

Further investigation shows that nothing is listening on port 8080. `ss -l | grep 8080` shows nothing.

Here is what `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` looks like:

```
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 21, 2014 4:36:16 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 21, 2014 4:49:45 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 21, 2014 4:56:55 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 21, 2014 5:03:11 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm a fairly novice linux user so perhaps its something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running Pidora on a Raspberry Pi. Perhaps that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just need to be more patient. I left it for a couple hours and now it seems to be working. I guess it was just initializing on the painfully slow Raspberry Pi during that period.